# Jmeter Loop : Changing path value on each loop iteration

Tags: loops, jmeter, beanshell

I am having a single HTTP Request which i need to execute with three different values in path as

Request : ${base_url}/1/file/object/${objPath}/file/${XLSXFileId}/process

1. /file/${XLSXFileId}/process
2. /file/${XLSFileId}/process
3. /file/${CSVFileId}/process

Is there any way to achieve this by using loop controller so that i don't need to make individual requests

Comment: Where do you get the values of these variables? ${XLSXFileId} ${XLSFileId} ${CSVFileId}

Comment: From previous requests in JSON Extractor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a [BeanShell PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor) as a child of the previous request after the JSON Extractor with the below code in the script area (The request which you extract the values of these variables from ${XLSXFileId} ${XLSFileId} ${CSVFileId}):

```
vars.put("Var_1",vars.get("XLSXFileId"));
vars.put("Var_2",vars.get("XLSFileId"));
vars.put("Var_3",vars.get("CSVFileId"));
```

Then add a [ForEach Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) with the below configurations:

- **Input variable prefix:** `Var`
- **Output variable name:** `MyVar`

Now add your request as a child of the ForEach Controller and edit the path to the below:

```
${base_url}/1/file/object/${objPath}/file/${MyVar}/process
```

This ForEach Controller will execute your request 3 times, each time the value of the variable **${MyVar}** will be different.